# jQuery: appendTo closest syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax, closest, appendto

I'm sure this is a simple problem. I have several rows in a table like this:

```
   <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="UsersSelect">
        <option value="user-whatever">User Whatever</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="EditButton"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></a>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('.EditButton').click(function() {
   $('<option>test</option>').appendTo($(this).closest('select.UsersSelect'));
...
});
```

This results nothing at all. I believe my error is in using $(this) improperly but can't figure out how I screwed it up.

Hopefully my goal is obvious enough. Just to clarify, I'm trying to append to the closest select ONLY, it will never be more than one at a time and always in the  directly above.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `select` isn't a sibling or parent, you have to do some more logic with your selector:

```
var container = $(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("select.UsersSelect");
$('<option>test</option>').appendTo(container);
```

Comment: All of the immediate answers are technically correct. But since this one was first, I selected it.

For future readers: I did not know closest() traveled up by parent or sibling. I thought it was literally line by line, this is not true.

Comment: @Joe -- Yup, `closest` travels up, `find` travels down

Comment: So this means it goes from the opening <tr> then moves downward/inside to whatever you specify. Good man. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`select.UsersSelect` is not a parent of `.EditButton`. That's why nothing is happening.

Use this instead:

```
$('.EditButton').click(function() {
   $(this)
     .closest("tr")
     .find("select.UsersSelect")
     .append('<option>test</option>');
   // ...
   return false;
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2qfF/)

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.EditButton').click(function() {
   $('<option>test</option>').appendTo($(this).closest('td').prev().find('select.UsersSelect'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Rc76n/)**

`.closest()` travels up the DOM and in your example it would go to the parent td, then the parent tr, the the table, missing the select altogether.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
$('<option>test</option>').appendTo($(this).closest('select.UsersSelect'));
```

to this:

```
$('<option>test</option>').appendTo($(this).closest('tr').find('select.UsersSelect'));
```

---

you need to traverse up to the `tr` with `.closest()` and then you can use `.find()` method to get the target.